# Protected health information in different countries

Tags: data-request, medical, privacy

I'm looking for a dataset that would gather the different categories of [protected health information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_health_information) (PHIs) in different countries. I am only interested in electronic health records.

---

For example, in the United States, PHIs are defined in [Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act (HIPAA) rules](http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/understanding/coveredentities/De-identification/guidance.html) (US regulations), and are classified into 19 categories:

```
(i) Names of patients and family members
(ii) Addresses and their components
(iii) Dates (month and day parts, unless the inclusion of the year part identities an individual to be older than 90 years old)
(iv) Explicit mention of ages over 89 years old
(v) Telephone and fax numbers
(vi) Social Security numbers
(vii) Medical record numbers
(viii) Health plan beneficiary numbers
(ix) Account numbers
(x) Certificate or license numbers
(xi) Vehicle identifiers and serial numbers
(xii) Device identifers and serial numbers
(xiii) Electronic mail addresses
(xiv) Web universal resource locators (URLs)
(xv) Internet protocol (IP) addresses
(xvi) Biometric identifiers
(xvii) Full face photographic images
(xviii) Employers
(xix) Any other unique identifying number, characteristic or code
```

Comment: In other countries, this would fall probably under data privacy laws, which differ in details by country. Your best bet maybe [International Council of Harminization](http://ich.org), which could have some information on that.